# Java Multithreading Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

If I launch for example five threads in main class that will be running parralell

```
final int TERMINAL_COUNT = 5;
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    Queue<Terminal> terminals = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i<= TERMINAL_COUNT; i++){
        terminals.offer(new Terminal(i, semaphore));
    }

    for(Terminal terminal : terminals) terminal.start();
 }
```

And class that carries them looks like

```
public class Terminal extends Thread {
private Dispetcher dispetcher;
private Semaphore semaphore;


public Terminal(int terminalId, Semaphore semaphore){
    dispetcher = new Dispetcher();
    this.semaphore = semaphore;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        ListIterator<Plane> pIt = dispetcher.getPlanes().listIterator();
        while (pIt.hasNext()){
            Plane p = pIt.next();

            if(!p.isArrived()) {
                //some code
                replacingPassangers(p);
            }
        }
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void replacingPassangers(Plane p) throws InterruptedException{
   semaphore.acquire();
    if(!p.isArrived()) {
        //replacing passangers
        p.setIsArrived(true);
    }
    semaphore.release();
}
}
```

So i need that after passengers is replaced by 1 thread the others skip methods logic with help of if(!p.isArriving) condition. But p.setIsArrived(true); doesn't affects this variable in other threads and as result all threads passing this condition... How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you maybe invert the sense of your condition?  If you expect only one plane to have arrived at any given time, then processing for just that plane seems like it would require `if (p.isArrived) { ... }`.

Comment: `isArrived` defaults to `false` and never seems to be set to `true`. Thus `if(!isArrived())` will always be `true` and execute the `then` part.

Comment: I would like to reproduce but some classes like Dispetcher and Passanger, could you please provide it?

Comment: done. Also added plane creator and passanger creator

Comment: How about creating a smaller example that demonstrates the same problem instead of having people to read this wall of code?