# Java Semaphor multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

If I launch for example five threads in main class that will be running parralell

```
final int TERMINAL_COUNT = 5;
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    Queue<Terminal> terminals = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i<= TERMINAL_COUNT; i++){
        terminals.offer(new Terminal(i, semaphore));
    }

    for(Terminal terminal : terminals) terminal.start();
 }
```

And class that carries them looks like

```
public class Terminal extends Thread {
private Dispetcher dispetcher;
private Semaphore semaphore;


public Terminal(int terminalId, Semaphore semaphore){
    dispetcher = new Dispetcher();
    this.semaphore = semaphore;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        ListIterator<Plane> pIt = dispetcher.getPlanes().listIterator();
        while (pIt.hasNext()){
            Plane p = pIt.next();

            if(!p.isArrived()) {
                //some code
                replacingPassangers(p);
            }
        }
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void replacingPassangers(Plane p) throws InterruptedException{
   semaphore.acquire();
    if(!p.isArrived()) {
        //replacing passangers
        p.setIsArrived(true);
    }
    semaphore.release();
}
}
```

So i need that after passengers is replaced by 1 thread the others skip methods logic with help of if(!p.isArriving) condition. But p.setIsArrived(true); doesn't affects this variable in other threads and as result all threads passing this condition... How can I fix it?

Comment: You simplified your code so much that I can't even reproduce. For me using a semaphore used as you do with only one permit, doesn't seem to be useful anymore you should use synchronized blocks and use your plane as mutex. And do it everywhere you read or modify something from your plane as it must be thread safe since it is a shared resource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Multithreading Semaphore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453343/java-multithreading-semaphore)